# Which jar contains com.sun.jdmk.security.sasl.Provider class file

Tags: java, jmx, jmxmp

I am implementing 'JMXMP Connectors With Simple Security' example from 'Java Dynamic Management Kit 5.1 Tutorial' Oracle documentation. Where can I find the source code of the examples?

Also, which jar contains the jar com.sun.jdmk.security.sasl.Provider or is it deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

First;

> [bean-validator-4.0.0.Alpha3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbeanvalidator400Alpha3jar.htm)

includes com.sun.jdmk.security.sasl.Provider class and also com.sun.jdmk.* package context.

**Also [open-dmk](https://opendmk.java.net/download/index.html) downloads have this class(com.sun.jdmk.security.sasl.Provider).**

Second;
On [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/6mdjrf82m/index.html) explained as;

> These tutorials are based on the example programs **shipped with the
>   Java DMK**. Each example is a set of Java source code files in a
>   separate subdirectory. The following table gives the location of the
>   main examples directory:

But I think [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/index.html)(*it seems same as which you are reading*) is not up to date. Maybe documentation was moved from old sun's java site and not updated. After Java DMK sources opened as open source Open DMK, It seems example directories not published or shipped with Open DMK.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use 'bean-validator-4.0.0.Alpha3.jar' file.
download it from

'http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbeanvalidator400Alpha3jar.htm'

[bean-validator-4.0.0.Alpha3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/bean/bean-validator-4.0.0.Alpha3.jar.zip)